# What does Suhrawardi mean by 'the caves of the mountains of Banu'l-Akhyaf'?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Suhrawardi, an Islamic and Persian sage wrote:

> The party of God will become divine, will praise God, will detach themselves and pass through the caves of the two mountains of Banu'l-Akhyaf to the two mountains of the Lesser Orient and Greater Orient, reaching the Gate of Gates.

**Q. What does Suhrawardi mean by the "caves of Banu'l-Akhyaf"?**

Comment: Banu al-Akhyaf بنو الأخياف in Arabic means siblings from the same mother but different fathers.

Answer (score -1):

Suhrawardi wrote things in code and allegory so that what he found would not be in the hands of anyone and only mystics and mystical philosophers would understand what he was thinking. And what facts he has achieved.
I do not think it is possible to easily discover his cryptic concepts on the web. To understand his thoughts, you must follow the path of mysticism and conduct to fully understand the meaning of what he says. It is as if you are reading a specialized article on brain surgery, while you have no major in medicine. Reading that article will not benefit you.

Comment: -1: This is ridiculous. It's quite easy to understand what al-Hallaj was attempting without going the way of mystics. What is difficult to understand is whether it is true and that can only be discovered by going the way of the mystics. Likewise with Suhrawardi. The same is true for modern physics - most bright college age students can understand General Relativity or Quantum Mechanics without actually doing the very difficult and advanced maths that goes along with it. Likewise, a brain surgeon who is interested in the public understanding of science ...

Comment: ... isn't going to advocate the general public to read specialised scientific articles but will write articles for the general public at various perspectives and levelscof education.